# Можно ли, из экземпляра класса иметь ссылку на его родителя и пользоваться им?

Tags: java, ооп, архитектура

Нужен совет по ООП.

Есть основной класс в котором скопилось очень много кода, хочу его разгрузить, то есть разбить по возможности на отдельные классы.

Допустим, у меня есть логический кусок, который я выношу в отдельный класс, но в нем достаточно часто используются члены главного класса. И появляется проблема выбора способа доступа к этим членам. Для решения рассматриваю такие варианты:

1. в доп. классе создать используемые переменные, и в конструкторе часть из них  инициализировать, часть из них передавать аргументами в нужный метод

*(какую проблему вижу)* повторный код, большой список аргументов (конструктор/метод)

2. в конструкторе доп. класса объявить параметр типа родительского класса, и при создании объекта доп. класса передавать в конструктор `this` (**то есть мы будем получать ссылку на родителя**) и по этой родительской ссылке юзать нужные поля

*(какую проблему вижу)* На сколько я знаю, считается плохой практикой передавать ссылку на родителя в объекты. Экземпляр ничего не должен знать что происходит вверх по иерархии, манипуляции идут Только вниз по иерархии. Правильно?

Не вариант этот кусок кода оставлять на месте.

Работать будет и так и так, но как сделать лучше? I need the best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно сама архитектура разделения не совсем удачно вами понимается. И на самом деле ваши классы все еще слишком "большие" (это по сути все-еще один класс, хоть и разделен в два файла).

Если возникает вопрос как же им делить совместные функции, значит их разделение не завершено и нужен еще и третий, и наверное четвертый и т.д. ... Каждый класс, как и метод, должен выполнять только одну функцию. Если это холдер, то он только отвечает за хранение и добавление/удаление данных. Если это фильтр, то он только фильтрует. Если это конвертер, то он только конвертирует.

А, вот если идет смешение функций - то вы пытаетесь вырастить "дракона", пусть и многоглавого, но эта зверюга сожрет ваше время и силы.

Выделяете больше классов. Они как и методы должны быть достаточно короткими и автономными. Представьте, что вы этот класс потом в другое приложение целиком запихнете, сможет ли оно там работать без переделок?

Одна функция = один класс, один класс = одна функция!

Comment: Я между прочим, пришел к такому же выводу, что я не достаточно отделил сущности. Самодостаточность, вот что вы описываете, для каждого объекта, это то что нужно стараться создовать. Полностью согласен с вашим ответом. Еще такой вопрос, данная проблема соовсе не проблема? Можно ведь так оставить, это все из за того что я хочу лучший код. Но тогда получается что по сути, в таких God классах проподает ооп и появляется процедурка.

Comment: да, совершенно верно

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае было бы неплохо знать саму задачу, а не её решения. Думаю можно было бы сделать так, чтобы родительский класс использовал дочерние. Или вообще разбить логику на несколько классов. Как вариант Ваш Родительский класс и Дочерний могут стать классами представляющими какую-либо логику, а поля и данные которые используются Родительским и Дочерним классами можно выделить в отдельный класс. Но опять же все зависит от задачи.